# Tailwind arbitrary variants and screen sizes

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Trying to use Tailwind arbitrary variants with screen sizes.

Objectives:

- on `sm` have last three children be red (and the rest neutral)
- on `md` have last two children be blue (and the rest neutral)
- on `lg` have all children be yellow (and the rest neutral)

My code:

```
<div className="grid grid-cols-4 gap-2">
<div className="col-span-4 md:col-span-2 lg:col-span-1 lg:bg-yellow-200 [&:not(:first-of-type)]:bg-red-500 md:[&:not(:nth-of-type(-n+2))]:bg-blue-200"
  >
    <div>
    <h2>Chapter-1</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
    <h2>Chapter-2</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
    <h2>Chapter-3</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
    <h2>Chapter-4</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which elements do you mean by "children"? Do you mean the `<li>` elements? Just wanted to check since your arbitrary variants match the `<div>` that the classes are attached to.

Comment: @Wongjn - yes, the "children" are the divs that relate to each of the chapters 1-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a base, use `&>div` to target the child `<div>`s.

> - on `sm` have last three children be red (and the rest neutral)

Use [`:nth-last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child) to select the last n<sup>th</sup> children with `[&>div:nth-last-child(-n+3)]`.

As `n` increases starting from `0`, `3`, `2` and `1` are the only positive integers evaluated from the formula, thus the third-last, second-last and last children will be selected.

To combine this with the `sm` stipulation, add `sm:`. Since we have further stipulations, add `max-md:` so that we no longer apply above the `md:` breakpoint:

```
sm:max-md:[&>div:nth-last-child(-n+3)]:bg-red-200
```

> - on `md` have last two children be blue (and the rest neutral)

Use similar `:nth-last-child` selector, but this time for one the last two with `[&>div:nth-last-child(-n+2)]`. Also add `md:` for the `md` stipulation and `max-lg:` to stop this from interfering with the later `lg` stipulation:

```
md:max-lg:[&>div:nth-last-child(-n+2)]:bg-blue-200
```

> - on `lg` have all children be yellow (and the rest neutral)

No `:nth-last-child` needed since it will be all children, `[&>div]`. Add `lg:` for the `lg` stipulation. No `max-*` variant needed since there are no more stipulations to "reset" for:

```
lg:[&>div]:bg-yellow-200
```

Full example:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-4 gap-2">
  <div class="col-span-4 md:col-span-2 lg:col-span-1 sm:max-md:[&>div:nth-last-child(-n+3)]:bg-red-500 md:max-lg:[&>div:nth-last-child(-n+2)]:bg-blue-200 lg:[&>div]:bg-yellow-200">
    <div>
      <h2>Chapter-1</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Chapter-2</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Chapter-3</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Chapter-4</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: very clear, thank you.